# Solving a set of nonlinear algebraic equations under inequalities constraints

Tags: equation-solving, nonlinear, inequalities

I just started today using Mathematica.

I want to solve the following four equations already written in the function "Solve" under four inequalities constraints and one unequal constraint.

`Solve[{4*x01 (p12*p21)^2 + 4*x02 (p12^2*p21*p22) + 2*x02 (p12^3*p21)*d1 - 
     4*(p12*p21)^2 == 
    0 && -4*x02 (p12^2*p21)*p22 - 2*x02 (p21)*(d1*p12^3) + 
     4*x02*(p12*p21)^2 == 0 && 
   c1*4*x01*(p12*p21)^2 + 4*c1*x02*p12^2*p21*p22 + 
     2*c1*x02*p21*d1*p12^3 == 0 && 
   c1*(-x02*(-2*p12*p21)*(-2*p12*p22 - d1*p12^2)) + 
     c2*(4*x02 (p12*p21)^2) - (4*(p12*p21)^2) == 0 && x02 >= 0 && 
   x01 >= 0 && p12*p21 != 0 && d1*p12/p21 >= 0 && p22/p21 >= 0}, {p12,
   p21, p22, x01, x02, c1, c2, d1}, Reals]`

I've fixed the code and now I'm getting this:

[image]

However, what I want, is to receive numerical values for the variables that solves all these equations and constraints.

So, in order to I receive numerical values for all variables I need to substitute one numerical value in one variable in this "answer" returned by Mathematica? In this case, how can I do this?

Or, there's still a way to Mathematica return to me numerical values at once?

Comment: Somehow you've got dashes instead of minus signs.  I'd just go into your code and make sure all are minus signs.  Then you need to replace the outside set of curly brackets with square brackets.

Comment: And add `Reals` as the last argument of `Solve[]`.

Comment: @JimBaldwin I did what you commented and editted the answer, please check.

Comment: Looks reasonable. Note you have 4 equations and 8 variables - so you won't get a numerical answer like $x=3.8$; 4 variables are expressed as functions of the other ones. If you want _any_ numerical solution, ust insert some values of 4 variables and you'll get the other 4.

Comment: @corey979 ok, but the system may be infeasible depending on the selected numerical values. Thank you.